# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute

Tags: java

I have removed all old Java 8 files/folders and reinstalled Java 11 in my machine. However when trying to run neo4j, it shows JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. Here are my [folders/files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHoRE.jpg) of jvm

I have tried following some questions to edit the etc/profile file, but still no success in getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer Java versions don't define `JAVA_HOME` anymore. You removed Java 8 but the environment variable wasn't removed. Neo4j tries to find something in the folder defined in `JAVA_HOME` which points to your old Java installation. Since you removed that folder, you get an error saying it can't find the folder.

You'd need to change `JAVA_HOME` so it points to your new Java installation since Java doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: i get this `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_333`

Comment: You have to change JAVA_HOME then. The value points to your old installation and it isn't found. I didn't see your image correctly, my bad. You'd have to modify `JAVA_HOME` since it's pointing to your old Java installation